# How to add custom property to Symfony Doctrine YAML mapping file

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, mapping, yaml

Can anyone tell me how to add custom property to doctrine ORM yml file?

My idea is to add a property like this:

```
fields:
    name:
        type: string
        localizable: true
```

Then I would like to get information about this **localizable** property by using

```
protected function getEntityMetadata($entity)
{
    $factory = new DisconnectedMetadataFactory($this->getContainer()->get('doctrine'));

    return $factory->getClassMetadata($entity)->getMetadata();
}
```

and then:

```
    $met    = $this->getEntityMetadata($bundle.'\\Entity\\'.$entity);
    $this->metadata = $met[0];
    $fields = $this->metadata->fieldMappings;

    if (isset($fields)) {

        foreach ($fields as $field => $fieldMapping) {
            if (isset($fieldMapping['localizable']) && $fieldMapping['localizable'] == true) {

                // Do sth with it
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way doctrine is written makes this awkward. It seems like you'd like to keep the Yaml mapping but just add a single property. I think you can create your own custom driver extending from the one provided. The Yaml driver has mostly private methods so overriding a little bit of the functionality is difficult, but it is possible.

I created a custom driver that extends from the `SimplifiedYamlDriver`. The naming of the driver is important because doctrine extension will try to load one of their drivers based what comes before `Driver`. It also does a strpos check for `Simplified` in the name, so I think the safest bet is to keep the original name completely and give the original an alias.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\SimplifiedYamlDriver as BaseDriver;

class SimplifiedYamlDriver extends BaseDriver
{
    public function loadMetadataForClass($className, ClassMetadata $metadata)
    {
        parent::loadMetadataForClass($className, $metadata);

        $element = $this->getElement($className);

        if (!isset($element['fields'])) {
            return;
        }

        foreach ($element['fields'] as $name => $fieldMapping) {
            if (isset($fieldMapping['localizable'])) {
                $original = $metadata->getFieldMapping($name);
                $additional = ['localizable' => $fieldMapping['localizable']];
                $newMapping = array_merge($original, $additional);
                $metadata->fieldMappings[$newMapping['fieldName']] = $newMapping;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I told Symfony to use this driver by overriding the class inside `app/config/parameters.yml`

```
parameters:
    doctrine.orm.metadata.yml.class: MyBundle\SimplifiedYamlDriver
```

Then I updated the mapping like in your example inside `MyBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Foo.orm.yml`

```
MyBundle\Entity\Foo:
    type: entity
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        text:
            type: string
            localizable: true
```

And I can fetch this mapping wherever I have access to doctrine with:

```
$mapping = $this
            ->getDoctrine()
            ->getEntityManager()
            ->getClassMetadata(Foo::class)
            ->getFieldMapping('text');
```

Will give me:

```
Array
(
    [fieldName] => text
    [type] => string
    [columnName] => text
    [localizable] => 1
)
```

Comment: This almost works. But the problem is that DoctrineExtensions (which probably works similar to that) stop working if I do as you wrote. I am extending Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\SimplifiedYamlDriver which is used by default so it should work, but it doesn't. Any idea why?

Comment: Hmm, that exact answer I posted worked for me. Maybe it's a difference in doctrine versions. I have ^2.5 in composer.json

Comment: Me too. doctrine/orm 2.5.4 and newest devmaster StofDoctrineExtensions

Localizable is shown but sluggable, blamable, timestampable stop working.

Comment: Maybe this driver should be somehow chained?

Comment: It took me a while, but I found the problem. Inside `ExtensionMetadataFactory` (~line 153) the doctrine extensions bundle tries to load a driver based on the original drivers name which is: `'Gedmo\Blameable\Mapping\Driver' . substr($driverName, 0, strpos($driverName, 'Driver')`. In my original answer this driver didn't exist so it used the fallback annotations driver (which fails because you don't use annotations). So the name was what broke it, I've updated the answer to use the same name as the default driver.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is impossible without rewriting a significant part of Doctrine DBAL. This would impact drivers (YAML, annotation...), meta data generator...

In your case, the simplest I see would be to add a custom type let's say `LocalizableString` (I guess at most you will need that and maybe `LocalizableText`). 
Adding a type is relatively straightforward, since you can extend a base type so you don't have to write any SQL. You can refer to Doctrine documentation [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html) and Doctrine bundle one [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/dbal.html#registering-custom-mapping-types-in-the-schematool).

Then you can just do:

```
$met    = $this->getEntityMetadata($bundle.'\\Entity\\'.$entity);
$this->metadata = $met[0];
$fields = $this->metadata->fieldMappings;

if (isset($fields)) {

    foreach ($fields as $field => $fieldMapping) {
        if ($this->getClassMetadata()->getTypeOfField($field) === 'localized_string') {

            // Do sth with it
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot do that, because I want to add this property to each type of field. So I would need to prepare a new type for each base types.

I know this is possible because DoctrineExtensions does this but I cannot understand how.

Comment: As far I know, DoctrineExtensions don't modify the original types. They add their own annotations, and have their own mecanism called when building metadata, that will keep track of "extensions-enabled" entities: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/Mapping/MappedEventSubscriber.php